# use lambda expression to count sum of f(i)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, scheme

I have function which count sum of f(i) for i in <a;b>

[image]

```
(define (F a b f)
      (if (> a b)
          0
          (+ (f a) (F (+ a 1) b f))
        )
)
```

Now I want transform it to use lambda like there: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.2

So I created:

```
(define (F7 a b f)
    (sum (lambda (x) (f x)) a
           (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) b
         )
)
```

But got error `UnhandledException: sum() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)`
After research I tried to change it to:

```
(define (F7 a b f)
    (sum ((lambda (x) (f x)) a)
           ((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) b)
         )
)
```

I got error: `UnhandledException: 'int' object is not iterable`

So I tried run code from link but when I put into jupyter code

```
(define (pi-sum a b)
  (sum (lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 2))))
       a
       (lambda (x) (+ x 4))
       b))
```

I got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "In [36]", line 14, col 1, in 'integral'
  File "In [35]", line 4, col 6, in 'sum'
UnhandledException: sum() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: You are writing Lisp code, but you are getting Python errors. I am not familiar with Jupyter, but you need to somehow tell it that what you are executing is Lisp (more precisely Scheme, as far as I can tell). At the moment, it tries to execute it as if it was Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (F7 a b f)
  (sum (lambda (x)(f x))
       a
       (lambda (x)(+ 1 x))
       b))
```